# Im having issues passing data from 1 page to an other with a service. Variable is undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

im filling my variable in the service with data but its undefined when i want to access it on the other page.ts. I dont know what im doing wrong because it'S working sometimes but not when i want to access data depended on ID's or anything like that.

SO here is my Service:

```js
export class OrderService {
  userID;
  orderID;
  pizza;
  pizzaindex;
  order: Order;

  private ordersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Order>;
  private orders: Observable<Order[]>;


  constructor(private NavController: NavController,private db: AngularFirestore, private httpService: HttpClient) {


    this.ordersCollection = db.collection<Order>("Bestellungen") ;
    this.orders = this.ordersCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data};
        })
      })
    )
   }

 getPizzaByNumber(number){
    console.log("getPizzaByNumber", number);
    this.getJSON().subscribe(res=>{
      res.forEach(element => {
        if(element.number == number){
          this.pizza = element;
          console.log("Found Pizza element: ", element);
          console.log("Found Pizza: ", this.pizza);
        }
      });

    })
  }

..... 
}
```

show-order page where i wanna set the variables from.
when i click on the "item" its supposed to fill the data in the service

HTML show-order

```html
 <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of order.pizzen; let pizzaindex = index">
          <ion-item lines="inset" button (click)="getClickedPizza(item, userID, orderID, pizzaindex)" >
              <ion-grid>
                <ion-row>
```

show-order.page.ts

```js
getClickedPizza(pizza, userID, orderID, pizzaindex){
  //getClickedPizza(pizza){
    console.log("userID", userID, "orderID", orderID, "pizzaindex", pizzaindex)
    this.OrderService.userID = userID;
    this.OrderService.orderID = orderID,
    this.OrderService.pizzaindex = pizzaindex;
    this.OrderService.getPizzaByNumber(pizza.number);
    this.NavController.navigateBack('extras');

  }
```

All good so far i get the data till here then wen i want to get the pizza from the service and define the pizza on my extras.page.ts it says that this.Orderservice.pizza is undefined

```js
export class ExtrasPage implements OnInit {
  pizza;
 userID;
  orderID;
  index;

ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ExtrasPage ngOnInit"); 
    console.log(this.ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params)

    this.userID = this.OrderService.userID;
    this.orderID = this.OrderService.orderID;
    this.index = this.OrderService.pizzaindex;

    console.log("Index", this.index)
    console.log("orderID:: ", this.orderID);

    console.log("THis pizza: ", this.OrderService.pizza)
    this.pizza = this.OrderService.pizza;
    if(typeof(this.index)== typeof(Number) && this.orderID){
      console.log("LoadPizza true");
      this.OrderService.getPizzaByNumber(this.clickedPizza.number);
      this.loadPizza();
    }

    console.log(" ExtrasPage this.OrderService.pizza", this.OrderService.pizza);
    this.pizza = this.OrderService.pizza;

    this.preis_k_string = (this.pizza.preis_k/100).toString().replace(".",",") + " €";
    this.preis_g_string = (this.pizza.preis_g/100).toString().replace(".",",") + " €";
    this.preis_f_string = (this.pizza.preis_f/100).toString().replace(".",",") + " €";

  }

async loadPizza() {
    console.log('2222 Todo..')
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Loading Todo..',
    });
    console.log('Loading Todo..')
    await loading.present();

    this.OrderService.getOrder(this.orderID).subscribe(res => {
      this.clickedPizza = res.pizzen[this.index]; 
      loading.dismiss();
      console.log("loadBestellung: ",res);


    });
  }
```

here my extras class where i want to show the data from the this.Ordersservice.pizza

As you can see here im getting the index and the orderID but the pizza is still undefined

```
ExtrasPage ngOnInit
extras.page.ts:64 {}
extras.page.ts:72 Index 0
extras.page.ts:73 orderID::  MwjgtIeNWik68RDygdrL
extras.page.ts:75 THis pizza:  undefined
extras.page.ts:83  ExtrasPage this.OrderService.pizza undefined

ExtrasPage.html:27 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ingredients' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ExtrasPage.html:31)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:39364)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38376)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:38670)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38383)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:38699)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:38377)
    at callViewAction (core.js:38742)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an asynchronous problem : when Angular tries to display the data, it is still `undefined`, because your `getJSON()` function is asynchronous and `this.pizza` is not initialized yet.

First, try to change your function in your service :

```js
async getPizzaByNumber(number) { // Add async here
    console.log("getPizzaByNumber", number);
    const res = await this.getJSON(); // Add await here
    // Use await/async or .then() instead of subscribe for promises
    if (!res) return;
    this.pizza = res.find((el) => el.number == number); // Better than a forEach loop
    if (pizza) {
      console.log("Found Pizza: ", this.pizza);
    }
  }
}
```

In show-order.ts :

```js
async getClickedPizza(pizza, userID, orderID, pizzaindex){ // Add async here
    console.log("userID", userID, "orderID", orderID, "pizzaindex", pizzaindex)
    this.OrderService.userID = userID;
    this.OrderService.orderID = orderID,
    this.OrderService.pizzaindex = pizzaindex;
    await this.OrderService.getPizzaByNumber(pizza.number); // Add await here
    this.NavController.navigateBack('extras');
  }
}
```

Then your error should disappear.